# What does this error mean when im trying to run a node.js file with a mysql database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, command-line-interface

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');
var inquirer = require('inquirer');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 8889,
    user: "root",
    password: "root",
    database: "bamazon"
})

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    displayProducts();
})

var displayProducts = function () {
  var query = "SELECT * FROM Products"
  connection.query(query, function(err, res) {
      for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
          console.log("Item ID: " + res[i].itemID + " || Product: " + res[i].productName + " || Department: " + res[i].productDepartment + " || Price: " + res[i].price + " || Stock: " + res[i].stockQuantity);
      }
      shoppingCart();
    })
};
```

[CLI error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djq5D.png)

If im reading right its something to do with my .length, but I dont see the problem with that line so any help on this?

Comment: That means in customer.js go to line 19 and see which variable you are trying to access with length property. that variable is null

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the length property of null. Since null doesn't have a length property you are getting an error.

Check Line 19 of customer.js

before trying to do a for loop with it console.log your res object and see what it contains.

Answer (score 1):

Your query didn't return any results, so the `res` parameter inside your `for` is `null` and has no property, hence the error you're getting.

Check if your database is up and running at `localhost:8889`.